# Combine / Group - ArcGIS attributes table

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, table, grouping, combine

I need to group several rows in a single one, combining data cell (mainly “text”) in Arcgis desktop 10.2.2. One cell could have several records separated by comma. I have attached a screenshot in order to explain what I want to do. I have used geoprocessing tools, but I can’t figure out this problem.

[image]

I thought that one solution could work with table in excel, but I didn’t know how to make it yet (not manually).

Comment: You are now discovering why one should never store codes as comma separated values!

Comment: You could use arcpy but you should put some code together before an answer is provided. To start you off, make a set of unique values for your field with duplicates. Then make an empty dict to store duplicate field values using set values as keys. Then use a searchcursor in a nested for loop cycling through your attribute table for each unique value in your set: For x in set, with arcpy.SearchCursor(AttriubuteTableorFeatureClass,[duplicateValueField, valuesToCombineField]) as cursor: if x in row[0]: for key, item in..then use collections defaultdict(set). Will give more detail after you try.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question you can use python and the `set` object. Below is the code that constructs the data storing the results in a dictionary. So all you need to do is work out how to write the contents of the dictionary to a table. *Hint: you'll want to be using an `insertCursor`*

```
import arcpy
import pprint

tbl = "tblSites"
fields = ["place","codes"] # these are fields in my test table
myDict = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        place = row[0]
        codes = row[1]

        # Strip out spaces
        codes = codes.replace(" ","")
        codelist = codes.split(",")

        # Store data in dictionary, updating item set object
        if myDict.has_key(place):
            mySet = myDict[place]
            for code in codelist:
                mySet.add(code)
            myDict[place] = mySet
        else:
            mySet = set()
            for code in codelist:
                mySet.add(code)
            myDict[place]=mySet

pprint.pprint(myDict)
```